# Cryptic Crossword Clue: Mind reading Pop Star is fashionable (7)

Tags: cryptic-clues, crossword-clues

Here is a British-style (cryptic) crossword clue:

Mind reading Pop Star is fashionable (7)

Let me know if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> PSYCHIC

Mind-reading

> = PSYCHIC

Pop Star

> = PSY

Fashionable

> = CHIC

Comment: Ok, that was easy....